# Why Child Control of CompositeControl not show design mode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, composite-controls, asp.net-customcontrol

IDE: Visual Studio 2019 Framework: .net Framework 4.7.2

Hello everyone, for the work project, I made a CompositeControl, which will contain a TextBox, and a WebControl.

My code as follows, and will explain my problem at the end.

**1.MemberDialog.cs**

This is a control used to select people or groups.

In design mode, a DesignMode.gif image will be displayed for developers.

On the web page, ViewUser.gif or ViewGroup.gif will be displayed according to PickStyle.

```c#
    public class MemberDialog : WebControl
    {

        public enum Mtype
        {
            Person,
            Group
        }

        private Mtype otypes;

        public Mtype PickerStyle
        {
            get
            {
                return this.otypes;
            }
            set
            {
                this.otypes = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
        {
            var strHtml = string.Empty;
            if (base.Site == null || !base.Site.DesignMode)
            {
                if (PickerStyle == Mtype.Person)
                {
                    strHtml = "<img src='ViewUser.gif'> ←Image For Picker User.";
                }
                else
                {
                    strHtml = "<img src='ViewGroup.gif'> ←Image For Picker Group.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strHtml = "<img src='DesignMode.gif'> ←Image For DesignMode.";
            }
            output.Write(strHtml);
        }

    }
```

**2.MyWebCustomControl.cs**

This CompositeControl contains a DropDownList and a MemberDialog.

The DropDownList control is used to determine the PickStyle of the MemberDialog.

```c#
    public class MyWebCustomControl : CompositeControl
    {

        private DropDownList _ddlPickStyle = new DropDownList();
        private MemberDialog _memberDialog = new MemberDialog();

        public MyWebCustomControl()
        {
            _ddlPickStyle.Items.Add("Person");
            _ddlPickStyle.Items.Add("Group");

            _memberDialog.PickerStyle = MemberDialog.Mtype.Person;

            this.PreRender += MyWebCustomControl_PreRender;
        }

        private void MyWebCustomControl_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_ddlPickStyle.SelectedValue == "Group")
            {
                _memberDialog.PickerStyle = MemberDialog.Mtype.Group;
            }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Clear();
            Controls.Add(_ddlPickStyle);
            Controls.Add(_memberDialog);
        }

    }
```

**3.WebForm.aspx**

Drag MyWebCustomControl into the editing area.

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <cc1:MyWebCustomControl ID="MyWebCustomControl1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

## My problem is as follows:

In design mode, MemberDialog does not display the content of the design mode (DesignMode.gif ←Image For DesignMode.), Instead it shows PageMode (ViewUser.gif ←Image For Picker User.).

Through Debugger, function RenderContents of MemberDialog, base.Site return null,
so the web page mode is displayed.

[image]

At present, my solution is to set the value of this.Site to MemberDialog when MyWebCustomControl Renders.

**MyWebCustomControl.cs**

```c#
    public class MyWebCustomControl : CompositeControl
    {

        ...

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            _memberDialog.Site = this.Site;
            base.Render(writer);
        }

    }
```

[image]

This solution solves my problem temporarily,

**but is it correct? Is there any other correct way to do it?**